# Why does subtracting weights add weights to other parts of the mesh?

Tags: weight-painting

So my problem is that I'm trying to subtract weight, and it works in some areas, but in other areas of the mesh it just adds unsubtractable weight to the mesh. Is this a bug, or is this something that I'm just doing horribly wrong? The mesh is not originally mine, and I'm pretty new to blender.

[image: Before using the subtract brush]
[image]

Here's the file: [image]

Comment: could you share the file or at least a part of it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added a download for the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off "Auto Normalize" and it'll work as expected.

What normalizing means:

Let's say we had a vertex group with four vertices that have a weight value of *0.1*, *0.3*, *0.45* and *0.7*.
Normalizing these values would mean that every weight is scaled up so that the highest value is 1. To achieve that, divide 1 with the highest value and multiply your other weight values with the result.
In our case this would mean *1* divided by *0.7* = *1,4285714286*.

If we apply this equation on our values, we get *0.14*, *0.43*, *0.64* and finally *1*.

*(Every value rounded to two decimal places.)*

Comment: Thank you so much, I must have accidentally clicked that at some point

Comment: A little explanation of what *Auto Normlize* is and what it does might be helpful here.

Comment: There you go :) Explained the term.